# Process Priority vs Thread Priority

Tags: linux, multithreading, operating-system, thread-priority

In Linux, a process is a set of threads. Each thread has its own priority! But does a process have a priority too? If so, how is it different from the thread priority? And when a new process is created, how are these values propagated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux implements (kernel level) Threads essentially as Processes. So you fall back to the good old process-priorities there.

See [NPTL](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Native_POSIX_Thread_Library) and [nice](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/nice) (for understanding that processes are the first ones to have priorities). Mostly defaults are applied - in case of threads, the thread is a copy, so its priorities should be copied too. Will certainly vary with varying schedulers.